# How do I optimize this integration loop?

Tags: python

I want to perform some calculations on a large dataset. The code can be found below, where I want to calculate the values for 'results_nr' over a large loop (1000 x 910) values. Can you help me out with optimizing this code? The code is already running for 3500 minutes so far... When picking a smaller loop (100 x 91), the code gives the result I'm aiming for, but the resulting dataset needs to be more detailed.

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

kr = 3.02607165e+00
knr = 8.06622179e+12
dE = 925.013
Ea = 2.09542112e+04
k_B = 0.69503476
C_x = 1.85784648

def cross_relaxation4(t):
    elem1=1
    elem2=1
    
    for item in list(range(len(d24_neighbourlist))):
        elem1 = elem1*((1-(doping/100) + (doping/100)*np.exp((-C_x*t)/((d24_neighbourlist0_nm[item])**6)))**(d24_neighbourlist1[item]))

    for items in list(range(len(a8_neighbourlist))):    
        elem2 = elem2*((1-(doping/100) + (doping/100)*np.exp((-C_x*t)/((a8_neighbourlist0_nm[items])**6)))**(a8_neighbourlist1[items]))
    
    return ((0.75*elem1) + (0.25*elem2))*np.exp(-(kr+knr*np.exp(-Ea/((k_B)*T)))*t)


doping_handmade = list(np.arange(0.1,10.01,0.01))
temperature_K_handmade = list(np.arange(300,1200.1,0.1))

results_nr = []

for doping in doping_handmade:
    for T in temperature_K_handmade:
        val,err = integrate.quad(cross_relaxation4,0,np.inf)
        results_nr.append(val*kr)
```

Comment: What are `d24_neighbourlist0_nm` and `a8_neighbourlist0_nm`?

Comment: You could start by removing the `list(...)` calls in the `for` loops (ie. around the `range(len(...))` as they are useless, and require allocating memory which is very slow. Besides, if you need to optimize, you need to profile. If you have never done profiling again, I would recommend reading about it, as it will greatly ease your optimization process.

Comment: Hmm, converting a NumPy array to list. That is an odd choice. You may want to study NumPy a bit more.

Comment: Also, since in `cross_relaxation4`, you don't need to know the value of `T` to compute `elem1` and `elem2`, but just `doping`, I would recommend computing them outside of `cross_relaxation`, in the `for doping in doping_handmade` loop, which would save some time. Similarly, you may want to compute ahead of time the `np.exp(-(kr+knr*np.exp(...)*t)`. To avoid having to know beforehand for which values of `t` you have to compute that, you could memoize these.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Both the neighbourlists are a list of values, respectively 1190 and 457 values long. They describe distances between atoms. I will have a look into profiling and the numpy answer.

Comment: Would this be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Welcome to the community, on top of the previous comments, if you convert it into numpy, the numba would have great potential to speed up your function, it basically convert Python into "lower" language, and the result sometimes greatly speed up the things up (potentinaly at same rate, that whole conversion into c++ would be) more here: https://youtu.be/x58W9A2lnQc

Comment: Numba is usually used as a crutch for code that doesn't use Numpy properly, and that would certainly be the case here. Anyway, [I answered this question on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/277888/25834) and am quite happy with the results.